# Return non empty objects form array

Tags: javascript

I am having array `person` of say 3 objects and form that i want to return objects named `description`. Now m using map to iterate over `person`, but what happens here is, if person is not having `description` then it returns `undefined`. I want at last to get array with only `description` objects(no undefined).

```js
const person = [
{abc: 'abc',description:{}},
{qwe:'qwe', def:'def'},
{abcd: 'abcd',description:{}}
]

console.log(person.map(indivi => indivi.description))
```

Comment: Add a `filter` before `map`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter them out with .filter:

```js
const person = [
    {abc: 'abc',description:{}},
    {qwe:'qwe', def:'def'},
    {abcd: 'abcd',description:{}}
]

const descriptions = person
    .filter(indivi => indivi.description)
    .map(indivi => indivi.description);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a `filter` to remove objects not having a `description` property, before calling `map` on objects.

```js
const person = [
{abc: 'abc',description:{}},
{qwe:'qwe', def:'def'},
{abcd: 'abcd',description:{}}
]

console.log(person.filter(t => t.description).map(indivi => indivi.description))
```